# lein run with strange behavior

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using lein for a while now, always working perfectly. Now, considering this:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (let [port (Integer/parseInt 
               (or (System/getenv "PORT") "8080"))]
    (run-server application {:port port :join? false})))
```

then:

```
lein run
```

Not happen, seems that it is take so much time to running or something like that.

Someone can help me with this problem.

My lein version is: Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM. (I tried with the new version. 2.5.1 too)

Comment: With that as the `-main` that lein runs, I wouldn't expect `lein run` to do anything interesting in the terminal, but I would expect to be able to visit port 8080 with my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I did mess actually was opening a websocket, then was trying to access the standard browser.

In probelm with lein here.

Sorry